# Confused about default Scheduling behavior in RxJS5

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs5

In RxJS4, the following code would freeze your environment:

```js
Rx.Observable.of(10)
  .repeat()
  .take(1)
  .subscribe(value => {
     console.log(value);
  });
```

That's because it would run `repeat` on an immediate scheduler, and never get to `take`. Now in RxJS5 there is no immediate Scheduler, but if I run that same code, everything works as expected. What exactly changed and what scheduler are we running on? I thought the default was *no* scheduler by default, and that would freeze `repeat` too, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The default scheduler in RxJS 5 is synchronous - what used to be called immediate.

(Bottom of [this page).](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md)

The default scheduler in RxJS 4 is not immediate, it's "default" which is now called "asap" - basically it scheduled on the microtask queue.

Semantically this should work no matter what scheduler you're on. Namely, it should have worked in 4. You have an infinite source stream of 10's and you take 1 of them then unsubscribe. That triggers the inner subscription of `repeat()` to be disposed, breaking your infinite loop. It might have been a bug in 4?